# Plotting Monthly repetitive data python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to figure out how to plot this data but can't figure out my mistake:

```
 Month      Year       Sales
January     2020       43
feburary    2020       23
March       2020       13
April       2020       11
May         2020        7
June        2020        2  
July        2020        1
August      2020        2
September   2020        22 
October     2020       11
November    2020        6
December    2020        3
January     2019        3
feburary    2019        11
March       2019        65 
April       2019        22
May         2019        33
June        2019        88
July        2019        44
August      2019        12
September   2019        32
October     2019        54
November    2019        76
December    2019        23
January     2018        12
feburary    2018        32
March       2018        234
April       2018        2432
May         2018        432
June        2018        324   
July        2018        12
August      2018        324
September   2018        89
October     2018        6
November    2018        46
December    2018        765
```

I tried the following

```
y = df["sales"]
x = df["Month"]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Which gives the following plot(The exact values are different as my data values posted here is changed):

[image]

How do I correct it so that my plot breaks off each time at december and plots a new line for a separate year?

Comment: I'm not certain but I believe you can fix this by using datetime datatypes

Comment: @Mike Can you please elaborate with some code?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a pandas DataFrame that looks like:

```
    year      month   sales
0   2020    January    43.0
1   2020   feburary    23.0
2   2020      March    13.0
3   2020      April    11.0
4   2020        May     7.0
5   2020       June     2.0
6   2020       July     1.0
7   2020     August     2.0
8   2020  September    22.0
9   2020    October    11.0
10  2020   November     6.0
11  2020   December     3.0
12  2019    January     3.0
13  2019   feburary    11.0
14  2019      March    65.0
15  2019      April    22.0
16  2019        May    33.0
17  2019       June    88.0
18  2019       July    44.0
19  2019     August    12.0
20  2019  September    32.0
21  2019    October    54.0
22  2019   November    76.0
23  2019   December    23.0
24  2018    January    12.0
25  2018   feburary    32.0
26  2018      March   234.0
27  2018      April  2432.0
28  2018        May   432.0
29  2018       June   324.0
30  2018       July    12.0
31  2018     August   324.0
32  2018  September    89.0
33  2018    October     6.0
34  2018   November    46.0
35  2018   December   765.0
```

We can use `df.groupby('year')` to generate the kind of parsing that you're looking for:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticklabels(df['month'].unique(), rotation=90)

for name, group in df.groupby('year'):
    ax.plot(group['month'], group['sales'], label=name)

ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In `ax.set_xticklabels(data.index.unique(level=1), rotation=90)`, Instead of `data`, did you mean `df`?

Comment: derp. ya that should work, though what I did was set ticklabels after the for loop using the cached data from inside the loop (should make no difference b/c the unique values are the same)

Comment: This should be the answer, I learned somthing today! Thanks @MichaelGreen

Comment: @MichaelGreen It still doesn't work buddy. It says `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` at the `ax.plot(data.index.unique(level=1), data)`

Comment: if you type df.index does pandas return you a MultiIndex object?

Comment: I optimized the code a bit, see if getting rid of the df.loc[(level_0, level_1),:] call helps (replaced with groupby, which is probably a better solution here for your particular problem anyways)

Comment: ...although at this point you don't need hierarchical indexing haha. Changed the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add plots to the same graph as:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('year_data.csv')

for year in data['Year'].unique():
    plt.plot(data[data['Year']==year]['Month'], data[data['Year']==year]['Sales'])

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

The above code gives something like:
[image: graph with multiple plots]

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your columns to DataTime datatypes:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                   'month': [2, 3],
                   'day': [4, 5]})

>>> pd.to_datetime(df)

0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
```

You should now be able to plot against your dates.

Comment: Yes it sort of worked. But now it's a single line from start date of "2018 january" to    
 "2020 December". How do I instead make it cyclic for each year? i.e. A separate line graph for each year?

Comment: Now that they're in datetimes if you want to you can just split your date values into three different series by year and then overlay the plots

Comment: Ok. Are you sure there isn't a better solution? It seems a little contrude. What if later I have to increase the number of years you know. Would have to manually change my code everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Your plotting at the moment is aggregating all the years in the same graph, so it actually "loop around" when you reach the end of the year.

You could split the dataframe in 12-month periods and actually plot on the same matplotlib subplot as different lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

######################
## DATA PREPARATION ##
######################

sales20 = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2020, 'Sales']
sales19 = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2019, 'Sales']


##############
## PLOTTING ##
##############

# Create a new figure
fig = plt.figure()
# Add a subplot to the figure
ax = fig.add_subplot()
# Add to the subplot two line plots labeled accordingly
ax.plot(df["Month"], sales20, label='2020')
ax.plot(df["Month"], sales19, label='2019')
# Add handy legend
ax.legend(loc='best')
# Finger crossed and show the graph
plt.show()
```

It's a bit of a quick and dirty solution I must admit...

A more elegant one would be to convert the dataframe to being indexed with a `datetime` index, look at the [Pandas docs on the matter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)